# Dynamic async function call gives javascript runtime error

Tags: function, typescript, asynchronous, dynamic, call

I use this in for loop to assign to variable in order to have flexible configurable solution.

The code below:

```
   defineRestApi (api, methodName, options = {}) {

        for (const type of Object.keys (api)) {
            for (const httpMethod of Object.keys (api[type])) {

                let paths = api[type][httpMethod]
                for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                    let path = paths[i].trim ()
                    let splitPath = path.split (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/)

                    let uppercaseMethod  = httpMethod.toUpperCase ()
                    let lowercaseMethod  = httpMethod.toLowerCase ()
                    let camelcaseMethod  = this.capitalize (lowercaseMethod)
                    let camelcaseSuffix  = splitPath.map (this.capitalize).join ('')
                    let underscoreSuffix = splitPath.map (x => x.trim ().toLowerCase ()).filter (x => x.length > 0).join ('_')

                    let camelcase  = type + camelcaseMethod + this.capitalize (camelcaseSuffix)
                    let underscore = type + '_' + lowercaseMethod + '_' + underscoreSuffix

                    if ('suffixes' in options) {
                        if ('camelcase' in options['suffixes'])
                            camelcase += options['suffixes']['camelcase']
                        if ('underscore' in options.suffixes)
                            underscore += options['suffixes']['underscore']
                    }

                    if ('underscore_suffix' in options)
                        underscore += options.underscoreSuffix;
                    if ('camelcase_suffix' in options)
                        camelcase += options.camelcaseSuffix;

                    let partial = async params => this[methodName] (path, type, uppercaseMethod, params || {})

                    this[camelcase]  = partial
                    this[underscore] = partial
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> Typescript 2.7.2, NativeScript

```
let partial = async params => this[methodName] (path, type, uppercaseMethod, params || {})
```

gives error

JS ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'params'. Expected ';' after variable declaration.

tsc --version 2.7.2

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es7",
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms",
        "**/*.aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

It looks like function expression with async is somehow wrong.

Comment: Can you provide more code? The given example seems fine.

Comment: Need to know the version of typescript. That syntax has been supported for a long long time. Either you're in another context as the previous comment or hinted at, or you're using an old old version

Comment: Node version is v9.8.0

Comment: It came out that the issue is NativeScript / TypeScript related...